# How to create multiple tabs in tkinter from different classes in python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
       self.notebook = ttk.Notebook()
       self.add_tab()
       self.notebook.grid(row=0)

    def add_tab(self):
        tab = Area(self.notebook)
        tab2 = Volume(self.notebook) 
        self.notebook.add(tab,text="Tag")
        self.notebook.add(tab2,text="Tag2")


class Area(Frame):
   def __init__(self,name,*args,**kwargs):
       Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
       self.label = Label(text="Hi This is Tab1")
       self.label.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
       self.name = name

class Volume(Frame):
   def __init__(self,name,*args,**kwargs):
       Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
       self.label = Label(text="Hi This is Tab2")
       self.label.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
       self.name = name

my_app = App()
```

The volume class label in overwriting the label of Area class in both the tabs
how i can solve this problem and how i can add different stuff of classes in different tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the widgets in each tab be a child of the tab frame. You aren't specifying the parent or master for the labels, so they are going into the root window.

Take notice of the use of `self` in the last line of this code:

```
class Area(Frame):
   def __init__(self,name,*args,**kwargs):
       Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
       self.label = Label(self, text="Hi This is Tab1")
```